# Filtering Excel via Power Automate and send Mail

Tags: excel, email, workflow, power-automate

I just got the permission to try out Power Automate.
We have only one thing running in Excel via VBA and should replace it with a new solution:
What does this Excel VBA:

1. Filtering Column A for each value in Column A
2. Copying the filtered content and create a new table with only this content
3. Take this new table and create a mail-draft for a recipient (mail adress is stored in another column)
4. Close table/Delete table
5. next record out of filter array based on Column A

I find many tutorials for Power Automate with iteration over arrays but i have no clue how to generate this initial array of possible criterias out of column A - the part with sending mail (and creating HTML tables within this mail) is shown often.

Comment: FYI, besides those great references shared by jkpieterse and Brian, the Power Automate Community also has quite some posts talking about similar problems and solutions: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Power-Automate/ct-p/MPACommunity. You can search for keywords like "excel", "filter", "mail", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to asking for access to Power Automate, also ask permission for Office Scripts. This allows you to record (and write) Office Script macro's which you can call from your Power Automate Flows.

The Script bit is needed to manipulate the Excel file and update the separate tables.

See this page for a starter on Office Scripts:
https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel-office-script-basics.asp

And this one for some example scripts:
https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel-office-script-examples.asp

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be looking into Office Scripts. You can find Microsoft's examples on Office Scripts under the Samples section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel). And you can find the Stackoverflow forum on Office Scripts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-scripts) if you have any specific questions.